# jQuery footer slide out panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added the following code from this jQuery footer tutorial. However, rather the footer show when you visit the page I would like it to be closed. So only when you need to view the footer you have to then click. Hope that makes sense, can anyone tell me which parts of the code need changing?

[jQuery Tutorial](http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Creating-A-Toggable-Bottom-Content-Panel-Using-jQuery-CSS.html)

Comment: You should show code that you have tried. Have you tried changing `isVisible` to `false`?

Comment: Have tried that but has not changed anything.